# Are EC2 instances charged when starting/stopping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I am trying to host an application on AWS. I am comparing hosting it on Lambda and on EC2, and was thinking about "sides costs".
Indeed with lambda I am charged for cold starts, and I was wondering if when starting/stopping an EC2 instance you're charged for this time, since my instance will take something between 1 or 2 minutes to start and stop.
Since I plan to start and shut down quite a lot of instances frequently it would represent a non negligible cost for me if I am charged for this period.

Comment: 99.99% of the time use Lambda if you can run it within 15 minutes - cold starts are 100% of the time less than 60 seconds so if the only differentiator for you is cold start vs EC2 start duration, then go with Lambda.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! Actually my concern is more about price here, this is why I'm considering EC2

Comment: Yes, Lambda will be cheaper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pay when the instance is in `RUNNING` state. From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-hour-billing/):

> If your instance is billed by the second, then you're billed for a minimum of 60 seconds each time a new instance is started—that is, when the instance enters the **running state**.

This is independent of your application on the instance.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will pay for the storage unit that is attached to the EC2 instance, even if the EC2 instance is stopped.